# What am i not getting right when using npx create-react-app <my-pro> that is resulting to this error?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

PS C:\Users\B E S T\Desktop\ReactTuts> npx create-react-app feastproj
node:internal/modules/package_json_reader:110
const parsed = modulesBinding.readPackageJSON(
^

Error: Invalid package config C:\Users\B E S T\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\which\package.json.
at read (node:internal/modules/package_json_reader:110:33)
at readPackage (node:internal/modules/package_json_reader:128:10)
at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:592:15)
at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:673:31)
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1135:27)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\B E S T\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\util\resolveCommand.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_PACKAGE_CONFIG'
}

Node.js v21.6.2

i try 'npm cache clear --force' and i also try 'npm config set registry [http://registry.npmjs.org/'](http://registry.npmjs.org/%27). Yet it does not seems to help.

Comment: Did you try following the note in the guide about uninstalling first? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Yes. I read it.  I have never installed create-react-app in global before. I am to use react for the first time. I installed node.js and npm currents versions. Then I use npx create-react-app <my_pro>. It prompted me for installation of create-react-app. Which I confirm. And then in attempting to create the app. It aborted with the error message. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Another potential issue is the spaces in your username folder (`B E S T`)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will work on that to see how it help.